# express.js request header "Accept" not being set

Tags: node.js, express, request, http-headers

I am trying to set "Accept" parameter of the request header to "application/pdf" in express.js inorder to download pdf, but the request is still going as "application/json". Not sure what I am doing wrong.

This is how I'm setting the headers:

```
    import request from "request";


    const additionalHeaders = {
       apikey: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
       accept:"application/pdf"
     }
    const options = {
        url: url,
        headers: additionalHeaders,
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
    };

            return request.get(options);
```

Comment: what is request ? (request module https://github.com/request/request ?)

Comment: As far as I know, there is a typo in the the `options` object, change the `additionalHeaders` to `additionHeaders`

Comment: Lmao ! You saw well ! @FelixFong